# Access Multiple Elements of same ID in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

If i have elements such as this

```
<img src='0.jpg' id='images' />
<img src='...' id='myEle' />
<img src='...' id='myEle' />
```

in jQuery can i do something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myEle').mouseup(function () {

        $('#images').attr("src", myEle.getNumber() + ".jpg"); 
    }
}
```

Obviously each element is sorted in the correct number format that corresponds to the `myEle` array number

Comment: Do you have control over the HTML? Elements should have unique IDs.

Comment: yes i do. i have figured out how to do it, if the elements are unique but i want to create one event handler. Can i do that with different Id's

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**Do not create markup that contains elements with duplicate IDs.** This will break things, and you will be [mauled by a velociraptor faster than you can say `"goto"`](http://xkcd.com/292/).

Use **classes** instead:

```
<img src='0.jpg' id='images' />
<img src='...' class='myEle' />
<img src='...' class='myEle' />
```

*then...*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.myEle').live('mouseup', function () {

        $('#images').attr("src", myEle.getNumber() + ".jpg"); 
    });
});
```

---

### Re: OP comment

*"How do i know which image is pressed?"*

Use the `this` keyword:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.myEle').live('mouseup', function () {

        $('#images').attr("src", $(this).attr('src')); 
    });
});
```

...I think that's what you're looking for.

[image: velociraptor]

Comment: im thinking from a c# prespective. where you can have two different buttons with the same event handdler

Comment: @Angel: I don't understand. Please clarify.

Comment: How do i know which image is pressed?

Comment: @Angel: in the callback, the value of `this` is the element (**not jQuery-ified**) that fired the event. See my edit.

Comment: We need to send some velociraptors at http://foundation.zurb.com/learn/features.html . (As of 28 aug 20014 `document.querySelectorAll('#main-content').length` in e.g. Chrome's developer tools gave 7.)

Answer (score 16):

If you've inherited code so horrible that you can only work with the faulty output, use `jQuery("[id=theidthatshouldbeaclassinstead]")` or `jQuery("[id*=theidthatshouldbeaclassinstead]")` if there are multiple ids for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

If multiple elements will share a certain property, you should assign class to them instead of id. So the resulting jquery code will look something like:

```
$('.myEle').mouseup();
```

ID is to be used to uniquely identify elements.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that having multiple elements with the same `id` is incorrect. However it is pretty easy to generate such code in general-purpose frameworks, for example in Django one may have more than one forms  in a single view with the same field `auto_id`. Thus it would be nice to have jQuery function which selects all of these elements so client-side Javascript code can check the length of returned list and trigger a client-side error / warning in such case.

Also do not forget that the value of `id` has to be escaped in CSS query. While recent versions of Chrome / Firefox have native support of `CSS.escape()`, IE may require a polyfill: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/CSS.escape

```
$.id = function(id) {
    // FF 54 generates warning when empty string is passed.
    if (typeof id !== 'string' || id === '') {
        return $();
    } else {
        // Support multiple ID's to detect content bugs.
        return $(document.querySelectorAll('#' + CSS.escape(id)))
    }
};
```