# Can't select newly created object with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been working with jquery for a while so this is quite embarrassing that i'm having issues with this. I created a new element but i can't select it with jquery, what can i do about this? This is the javascript i used to create the element

```
$('<div id="test">blah</div>').insertAfter('#ref');
```

the html is

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="ref"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

i then tried this

```
$('#test').click(function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

but it does not work... i need help  here

Comment: Install FireBug on your browser and go to Console tab to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   $('#test').live('click', function(){
     $(this).remove();
   });
```

Comment: `.live()` only helps if the handler is bound before the element is added. In this case, he is adding the element first, so `.click` should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a JSFiddle showing that your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/YqEMa/

It is likely that you have not placed your Javascript within a jQuery "document ready" handler. Wrap your Javascript like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('<div id="test">blah</div>').insertAfter('#ref');
    $('#test').click(function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

This will ensure that the DOM has loaded before your Javascript runs.

Also, of course you should ensure that your script is within `<script>` tags.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want the element you've just inserted to be clicked (rather than all `#test` elements whenever they exist in the page's lifecycle), you can bind the event to the newly created element:

```
$('<div id="test">blah</div>')
    .click(function(){
        $(this).remove();
    })
    .insertAfter('#ref');
```

Comment: You shouldn't create multiple elements with the same id anyway.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789859/access-multiple-elements-of-same-id-in-jquery

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham The same ID, I think you mean – and you're right. As long as you remove the previous element with this ID before you insert the new one, there's nothing wrong with it. And this technique probably means you can lose the ID anyway.