# Issue with jquery toggle

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, toggle

I am using jquery toggle to show a div with content. Not sure how to explain the issue I am having, but if you go to my test page and click on the first link for Similar Movies (it coincides with the movie 500 Days of Summer) you'll see a panel open with the similar movies. If you go to the next Similar Movies link (coinciding with 10 Things I Hate About You) you'll see that it still controls the first set of movies, meaning it toggles the panel up and down. In fact, all of the Similar Movies links control the first panel. Not sure how to fix this. ***REMOVED LINK- NO LONGER NECESSARY- THANKS!**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".flip").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
</script> 

<div class="flip">Similar Movies
</div><!-- end of flip-->

    <div id="panel">
similar movies are echoed here from a database using php...
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have more than just one `<div>` with an `id` of "panel"?

Comment: IDs **must** be unique. Try using classes instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using an ID for your panels, use a class, like this:

```
<div class="panel">
  similar movies are echoed here from a database using php...
</div>
```

Then in your jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".flip").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

Using the same ID on more than one element is not recommended, and will [especially present problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789859/access-multiple-elements-of-same-id-in-jquery) when using jQuery.

Comment: Wow that was quick! That worked thank you. I have panel as an ID because of another script (CursorDivScroll) I am using that only recognizes an ID not a class.

Answer (score 0):

that's because you have many div with the same "id". You can fix it using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".flip").click(function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because your click function is only toggling the div with id of panel, which is the first id.  If you have other div's with this id, they will be ignored since id's must be unique and jQuery will just find the first id with the specified value and work with it.  You should change from `id="panel"` to `class="panel"` and modify your jQuery function to look for the next sibling element with class `panel` and toggle it.

The code could look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.flip').click(function(){
        $(this).next('.panel').slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like;

```
<div class="container">
<div class="flip">Similar Movies
</div><!-- end of flip-->

    <div class="panel">
similar movies are echoed here from a database using php...
</div>
</div>

var panel;
$(".flip").click(function(){
    panel = $(this).parent('.container').children('.panel');
    panel.slideToggle("slow");
 })
```