# Append to body then remove - can't get it to remove

Tags: jquery

I've a very simple modal window that appends the body - clicking the close button should remove it I thought this would do it but no. I've tried $(this).remove(); and it took out the button but not the appended text - where have I gone wrong?

```
$(function(){
var qrCodeDiv='<div id="qrBlock"><a href="#" class="closeQR">X</a></div>'

$(".add").click(function(){ 
$('body').append(qrCodeDiv); 
}); 

$('a.closeQR').live("click", function() {
$('body').remove(qrCodeDiv); 
});
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`.remove()` does not accept an arbitrary HTML string](http://api.jquery.com/remove/). Such syntax is specifically useful for creating elements, but that's not what `.remove()` does.

Change it to `$('body').remove('#qrBlock')` or simply `$('#qrBlock').remove()`.

---

Note that the code in your question will insert multiple elements with the same ID when the `click` callback runs more than once, [which is a **big** no-no and will lead to undefined behavior.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4789863/139010)

Comment: Somehow I'd never noticed the `.remove(selector)` syntax... neat.

Comment: Cool thanks - the second one did the trick. I also added in a fadeOut transition

    $("#qrBlock").fadeOut(800, function() { $("#qrBlock").remove(); });

Comment: Oh and yeah I was aware of multiple insert, but when the link is clicked the div covers it so it can't be clicked again - that's why I was so keen on having the code removed from the page rather than just fading it out.