# Filling inputs by clicking on a div of a choice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to fill the form by clicking on a div of my choice. Each div has different info.

My divs -

```
<div class="ab">
<ul>
    <li data-key="name">Sahar Raj</li>
    <li data-key="address">Address.</li>
    <li data-key="city">City</li>
    <li data-key="state">State</li>
    <li data-key="pin">Pin</li>
    <li data-key="phone">9876543210</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="ab">
<ul>
    <li data-key="name">Some Name2</li>
    <li data-key="address">Address2</li>
    <li data-key="city">City3</li>
    <li data-key="state">State4</li>
    <li data-key="pin">Pin5</li>
    <li data-key="phone">Phone2</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="ab">
<ul>
    <li data-key="name">Some Name3</li>
    <li data-key="address">Address3</li>
    <li data-key="city">City3</li>
    <li data-key="state">State3</li>
    <li data-key="pin">Pin3</li>
    <li data-key="phone">Phone3</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Form -

```
<div class="formcontainer">
<input class="required" type="text" name="name" />
<textarea name="address" class="required"></textarea>
<input class="required" type="text" name="city" />
<input class="required" type="text" name="state" />
<input class="required" type="text" name="pin" />
<input class="required" type="text" name="phone" />
</div>
```

Script -

```
$('div.ab').click(function () {
    $('.formcontainer').children().each(function() {
         // Get the corresponding key value from li.
         var $this =  $(this),
             key = $this.attr('name');
         // Find the li with that key
        var txt = $('.ab li[data-key="'+ key +'"]').text();

        $this.val(txt);
    });
});
```

Initially i tried with this much. I've three divs with different info. But the form is getting filled with the content of all the three divs. Then i added this script so that on hover, it will add the class `clix` to the divs -

```
$("#clikadd").hover(function() {
$(this).addClass("clix");
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass("clix");
});
```

I added `clickadd` ID to all the divs and changed the class in the previous script from `div.ab` to `div.clix`. Its not working. Any idea?

Comment: You said _"I added `clickadd` ID to all the divs"_...You may benefit from looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789859/access-multiple-elements-of-same-id-in-jquery -- please note the accepted answer in thatpost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

You can just use the `this` context to know which div was clicked on. You that instead of a general selector like `$('.ab')` that selects all divs.

**JS**

```
$('div.ab').click(function () {

    var $divClicked = $(this);
    $('.formcontainer').children().each(function () {
        // Get the corresponding key value from li.
        var $this = $(this),
            key = $this.attr('name');

        // Find the li with that key
        var txt = $divClicked.find('li[data-key="' + key + '"]').text();

        $this.val(txt);
    });
});
```

### **[Check Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/dKKBy/1/)**

Comment: @SagarRaj.. Check updated code.. There is a better way in which you can do it