# How to move dataTables search box inside Bootstrap container? JSFiddle included

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, search, datatable, containers

I want to move the [dataTables](https://datatables.net/) search box inside the Bootstrap container. It works OUTSIDE the container, but not inside the container. Take a look at the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/DanielFragaBR/ALNvR/

```
Search (works!) : <input type="text" id="searchbox">
<div class="container">
Search inside container (fail): <input type="text" id="searchbox">
```

Comment: This was answered here by Rpiechura:

http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/62021#Comment_62021

_"You can't have multiple items with the same ID. Jquery will only return the first item that matches, so since you had 3 items with all the same Id it found the first one to work and returned it. If you rename them to be Searchbox 1, 2 and 3 than the filter will work with all 3 of them (after changing the selector obviously)"_. Now everything works ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example does not work because of duplicate IDs. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789859/access-multiple-elements-of-same-id-in-jquery).

The jquery call

```
$("#searchbox").keyup(function() { ... })
```

actually binds the function as keyup event handler to the first element with id *searchbox*.

Remove other elements with *searchbox* id or turn *searchbox* to class and update jquery selector to select elements by class:

*markup:*

```
...
Search (works!) : <input type="text" class="searchbox">
<div class="container">
Search inside container (fail): <input type="text" class="searchbox">
...
```

*javascript:*

```
...
$(".searchbox").keyup(function() {
...
```

Comment: All right, too late with the answer :)
As this was my first answer on SO, it took longer to type it than I expected...

Answer (score 1):

Declare a span with a class

```
<span id="searchFilter"></span>
```

then you can set your filter box in this using this

Add this in document ready function

```
$('div.dataTables_filter').appendTo(".searchField");
```

this will work out. Have a try. Thanks.