# HTML tables getting specific table row using id

Tags: javascript, html

i have two rows with same id in two different tables , i need both of these rows.i can get first using getElementById , but not able to get second. i have both table id's and row ids ,
is there any way to get  that  row directly by by using its  table reference  ?

Comment: You shouldn't be using an `id` more than once. ID's are used to target a specific element (One of) If you want to target more than one element then you should use a `class`. If you edit your question and display some source code you will find people can give you an example of how to fix your problem. No source code = nothing to work with.

Comment: If you have no control over the table markup you can try some of the answers found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789859/access-multiple-elements-of-same-id-in-jquery, but otherwise you need to change your markup to use classes instead of the id tag. Each id tag should only exist once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have document wide unique ID ([HTML4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id)) in ideal case.

In your case it will be more beneficial to use CSS Selector(`nth-child`) with the help of JS or JQuery. You may not even choose to use class, you can just work with `<tr>`. Follow the link here([MDN Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)) for CSS Selector reference.

Comment: DOM has two div left and right each div has two tables and each table has rows with same id though both are different rows ,in UI it looks similar row .. i need highlight newly added row .well i am getting first row using getElementBy Id and second using table.rows looping till  i get my desired row

Comment: when you call getElementById, it searches for one unique ID. And because of the lax nature of html, it usually returns you the first one it finds in case there are multiple similar id's in the same document. So, no matter how many times you call the function, it will most likely return the element associated with the first instance of the id you are looking for.

Comment: On the other hand, using css selector, you can preset the graphical formatting beforehand. You don't even need to bother when new rows are populated. If in css you apply special formatting to the last row or say, the n'th row, it will apply the formatting to the appropriate one always.

Answer (score 2):

HTML page should have distinct ids.
Use class name to fetch those rows on class basis

Answer (score 2):

Give them class say `tablerows`, as you can not have two elements with same `id`

Now get them one by one

```
var cusid_ele = document.getElementsByClassName('tablerows');
for (var i = 0; i < cusid_ele.length; ++i) {
    var item = cusid_ele[i];  
    // Do whatever you want to do with this itm
}
```

Comment: Looping over all the table rows in much less efficient, but if you have no control over the markup this would provide a way to find the second row that has the same id.

Comment: But their are just two `rows`, Looping them is not inefficient.

Comment: The OP never said there were just two rows, only that there were two rows he needed to find. I still upvoted your answer, I just wanted to point out the efficiency problem if there were a lot of rows. Yours is the only way I know to solve this question if he can't or won't change the markup.

Comment: Yes you are right if the number of rows are large. Thanks for pointing it out.