# Why i can't get id value from button to send with my ajax jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, button

i don't know what wrong with my script, but the script can't get the id value of my button. actually it get only first id but for second and etc still shown as first id. here my script

```
$('#list').on('click','#ed', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("value");

    $.ajax({
        url: 'template/edit.php?id='+id,
        type: 'get',
        data: {ed: id}
    })
    .done(function(fil) {
        $('#modal').modal('show');
        $('#plc_form').html(fil);
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    });
});
```

and this is my button script

```
<button id="ed" value="<?php echo $row['0']?>" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</button>
```

i use php to fill button value and it works, but when i send value with my ajax to process server it always get only first id.

Comment: Do you have more than one button with `id="ed"`? IDs are supposed to be unique, use a class instead.

Comment: Why are you sending the id in both `id='+id` and `data: {ed: id}`?

Comment: Your question is confusing, do you want the ID of the button or the value of the button? Use `$(this).val()` to get the value.

Comment: Use View Source to check the HTML to make sure all the buttons have different values. Maybe the problem is in the PHP that's creating the HTML.

Comment: @Barmar -  I was just going to ask `how many of these buttons to you have`...

Comment: Please create an [mcve] that shows more of the HTML and demonstrates the problem. You can replace the AJAX call with `console.log(id)`.

Comment: @Barmar i have used method console.log(id) and it get right value for each id. and i have try check in PHP side if there is wrong and yes

i used this method `$id = isset($_GET['ed']) && $_GET['ed'];` to get id value and always got first value

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your first line:

```
$('#list').on('click','#ed', function(){
```

You have specified the optional selector parameter for jQuery's `on()` method. This will filter what elements are listening for the click event, in your case it is limited to the button with the ID `#ed`.

Also just a hunch, but since you posted your html with php I'm guessing the following line:

```
<button id="ed" value="<?php echo $row['0']?>" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</button>
```

is inside a loop? You might want to avoid creating multiple elements with the same ID on the same page. See this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4789863/9560897.

**Edit: Per OP's comment - "ed" should have been the `name` attribute instead of the `id`.**

It would be better to specify a class with your buttons and use that class as the selector for your click method as follows:

```
<button name="ed" value="<?php echo $row['0']?>" class="my-btn-class btn btn-warning">Edit</button>
```

And

```
$('#list').on('click', '.my-btn-class', function(){
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. i followed your method and switch my ID with class but it still not work. i have check on PHP Side i think there is problem but i don't know.

i used this method to get value `$id = isset($_GET['ed']) && $_GET['ed'];` maybe there is wrong

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the `name` attribute for the button. This will submit the button's `value` keyed by "ed" and should be available in `$_GET`.